# How to implement FragmentActivity as Fragment?

Tags: java, android, view, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I'm new at making apps for Android and I'm now making my first app and I'm having issues.

I've successfully made myself a navigation drawer following this tutorial: 
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

I have found this example which does exactly what I need - parsing XML and showing it as a list with images opening a more detailed view:
http://techiedreams.com/android-rss-reader-part-two-offline-reading-swipe-through-detail-views/

I have huge problems implementing the last example into my app (consisting of the first link) as the example uses a FragmentActivity while my app creates new Fragments from my MainActivity (*I know FragmentActivity and Fragments are different*).

**How MainActivity creates new fragments:**

```
private void displayView(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new NewsFragment();
                break; }
```

I need to make a Fragment consisting of what is inside of **SplashActivity**.

What would I need to do to implement **SplashActivity** into my MainActivity (and thus create a new Fragment of it)? Would I need to convert the FragmentActivity to a Fragment, or would I need to find a whole new solution?

If you would need and want to try it out yourself everything is available from the links above. As I'm a total beginner I really hope I can use the example above as it suits my app perfect.

**SplashActivity:**

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

private String RSSFEEDURL = "http://www.nordichardware.se/feed/rss.html";
RSSFeed feed;
String fileName;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    fileName = "TDRSSFeed.td";

    File feedFile = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath(fileName);

    ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() == null) {

        // No connectivity. Check if feed File exists
        if (!feedFile.exists()) {

            // No connectivity & Feed file doesn't exist: Show alert to exit
            // & check for connectivity
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage(
                    "Unable to reach server, \nPlease check your connectivity.")
                    .setTitle("TD RSS Reader")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Exit",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {
                                    finish();
                                }
                            });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        } else {

            // No connectivty and file exists: Read feed from the File
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,
                    "No connectivity! Reading last update...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            feed = ReadFeed(fileName);
            startLisActivity(feed);
        }

    } else {

        // Connected - Start parsing
        new AsyncLoadXMLFeed().execute();

    }

}

private void startLisActivity(RSSFeed feed) {

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("feed", feed);

    // launch List activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(intent);

    // kill this activity
    finish();

}

private class AsyncLoadXMLFeed extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        // Obtain feed
        DOMParser myParser = new DOMParser();
        feed = myParser.parseXml(RSSFEEDURL);
        if (feed != null && feed.getItemCount() > 0)
            WriteFeed(feed);
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        startLisActivity(feed);
    }

}

// Method to write the feed to the File
private void WriteFeed(RSSFeed data) {

    FileOutputStream fOut = null;
    ObjectOutputStream osw = null;

    try {
        fOut = openFileOutput(fileName, MODE_PRIVATE);
        osw = new ObjectOutputStream(fOut);
        osw.writeObject(data);
        osw.flush();
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    finally {
        try {
            fOut.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

// Method to read the feed from the File
private RSSFeed ReadFeed(String fName) {

    FileInputStream fIn = null;
    ObjectInputStream isr = null;

    RSSFeed _feed = null;
    File feedFile = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath(fileName);
    if (!feedFile.exists())
        return null;

    try {
        fIn = openFileInput(fName);
        isr = new ObjectInputStream(fIn);

        _feed = (RSSFeed) isr.readObject();
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    finally {
        try {
            fIn.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return _feed;

}

}
```

Comment: Converting a FragmentActivity into a Fragment is a bit like converting a Chicken into an Egg. I suggest you read the [Fragments tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html) first before doing stunts like that.

Comment: Thank you for your input but I'm aware of that, it was more a question for experienced. My question is how I can implement the example into my app. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a fragment you have to extend the fragment class.

```
  public class SplashActivity extends Fragment{
 //your fragment code.
 }

 //Also you need to actually use the fragment to do this you can create an intent and      start the intent or you can try
  FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
```